# Actionscript 2.0 visible property, movieclip/image overlap, it is blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So here I have two layers which are movie clips.They are stacked in the same place; They are named: ninja and ninja_mc
The code below works and it makes 2nd image(ninja_mc) hidden by default and when I mouse over my original image(ninja), that 2nd image replaces the original one:

```
ninja_mc._visible = false;

ninja.onRollOver = function(){
    ninja_mc._visible = true;
}
ninja.onRollOut = function(){
    ninja_mc._visible = false;
}
```

So what I am trying to do, (which is incorrect) and makes both of the images blinking:
I am trying to accomplish: while I mouse over my original image, the modified image(ninja_mc) pop up and the original one hides instead. So they do not stack each other;

```
ninja_mc._visible = false;

ninja.onRollOver = function(){
    ninja._visible = false;
    ninja_mc._visible = true;
}
ninja.onRollOut = function(){
    ninja._visible = true;
    ninja_mc._visible = false;
}
```

+1 everyone who is willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a transparent movieclip as overlay and assign your code to that one. It should work then.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
I had to duplicate the ninja layer, make a movie clip of the duplicated layer, then change blending mode to screen(so it might be transparent), change the visibility of the new movie clip along with ninja_mc(in the actionscript frame) and at the end, just make it visible - off by default.
Thank you anyway!